# Изучение многопоточного программирования

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность

Просматривая вакансии на должность C/C++ программиста, заметил, что знаний синтаксиса, ООП и алгоритмов недостаточно. В большинстве случаев к вышеперечисленному добавляется так называемое "многопоточное программирование". Выяснил, что существует множество технологий.

- С одной стороны, существует Qt, в котором эта тема наверняка как-то  обыграна.
- С другой стороны, существует весьма популярный OpenMP
- Ещё существует boost/Thread, а само слово boost встречается в вакансиях так же часто, как и "многопоточное программирование"

Видел уже много вопросов в стиле "Что почитать? Какие сайты посоветуете?". Мне же хотелось бы узнать, какие технологии на сегодняшний день являются самыми актуальными. Так же критерием выбора является сложность. В MFC тоже реализована многопоточность, но для этого нужно изучить WinApi, потом MFC, потом только можно будет приступить непосредственно к многопоточности. К тому же не факт, что front-end навыки мне пригодятся.

Резюмирую все вышесказанное: хотелось бы выбрать *актуальную* технологию, *основы* который реально постигнуть за *неделю* активного и упорного изучения. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: pthreads (но это в \*nix).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Наверное, надо понять, что такое потоки (threads) вообще, как они создаются, как их можно прерывать, как они заканчиваются. Далее самое сложное - механизмы синхронизации: всякие мьютексы, семафоры, барьеры, условные переменные. Для начала разберите и реализуйте паттерн "производитель-потребитель" (producent-consumer). Тогда многое станет ясно.

Лучше, наверное, начать с низкоуровневых реализаций, с уровня API системы. Разные boost.Thread, C++11 Thread, Qt::Thread - ООП-обертки, удобные и более безопасные, но довольно прозрачно отражающие низкоуровневые принципы реализации.

Что почитать... Обычно в книгах по API ОС все это описывается. По общим вопросам у Танненбаума в книге по ОС есть довольно неплохой раздел. Есть книжка по C++11 Thread, в том числе на русском.

Comment: Возможно, что вопросы нанимателей не совсем про "многопоточное программирование". Возможно, они пытаются спросить про конкурентное программирование, а вещи это несколько разные. Многопоточность -- штука логическая (типа "мухи" в одном потоке, "котлеты" -- в другом). Конкурентность -- организация параллельных вычислений в многопроцессорной/многоядерной среде. Приобрела особую актуальность с распространением многоядерных процессоров.

Comment: @mikillskegg, мне кажется для начала надо бы что-нибудь еще попроще, чем producent-consumer.

Например, параллельно посчитать сумму элементов массива.

@artyomdevyatov, главное тут практика. Берите любые задачи и думайте, как их распараллелить. Пробуйте писать (и **обязательно измерять**)

--

А вообще перечитал вопрос и задумался (сам оценить это не могу) о реальности освоения **основ** темы **за неделю**. 

Я имею в виду практические основы, т.е. чтобы в результате можно было начать писать работоспособные программы. Видимо слишком много подводных камней вообще вижу в этой теме.

Comment: Перестроить мышление на параллельные алгоритмы проще, чем например, на квантовые. Раньше начнете, раньше закончите

Comment: @avp статьи на эту тему, они несколько пугают. Утверждают, что всё хорошо, пока процессор один. Если их несколько -- всё значительно хуже. Т.е. годами работавшие многопоточные приложения начинают глючить.

Comment: @alexlz, в том то и дело. Самое сложное в многопоточности (именно в ней) - это отладка. Понятно, что при многопроцессорности вылезают ошибки реально одновременного доступа.

Вообще-то (для себя) я лет 25 назад сформулировал принцип идеальной среды параллельного программирования - "один процесс - один процессор и никакой shared memory".

Надеюсь, что в конце-концов так и случится, причем с развитием сегодняшних FPGA во что-то новое, процессоры (нужного вида) будут динамически создаваться под задачи.

Comment: @avp (1) ежели всерьёз -- так я не шибко разбираюсь (2) отладка? Хм. для ошибок, трудно уловимых и практически неповторимых, отладка становиться каким-то гаданием (3) 25 лет назад был принцип, а 10 лет назад электроника уткнулась в барьер по частоте, и полезли многоядерные процессоры, которым Ваш принцип -- до лампочки. (4) shared memory. Можно обмениваться сообщениями, как в erlang, но там свои тараканы. Так что и от shared memory не уйти...

@renegator Вы своё уже перестроили? Не поделитесь впечатлениями?

Comment: Освоение MPI затруднений не вызвало. Попытка осмыслить квантовые вычисления привела к одному выводу - если D-Wave доведут свой аппарат до ума, все мои системы шифрования пойдут на свалку

Comment: @renegator, все правильно, ведь MPI это параллельный API через обмен сообщениями. А вот про квантовые вычисления я читал пару статей, но так и не понял, как там программировать.

@alexlz, конечно, сейчас многоядерные процессоры это единственный способ считать быстро. Но, представьте, что произойдет если будет освоен терагерцевый диапазон для "микроразмерных" передатчиков. Провода внутри "коробочки" станут не нужны. Даже CPU с памятью будет общаться без них. И т.д. 

Парадигма программирования изменится, центр тяжести сместится в тот же MPI. И проблема когерентности кэшей отпадет сама собой.

Comment: @avp Ну вот когда будет. А пока что даже прогнозы по количеству ядер сбываются медленнее, чем представлялось несколько лет назад.

Comment: @mikillskegg, Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. А книга Танненбаума случайно не "Современные операционные системы" называется? Просто у него много книг по ОС.
Не могли бы вы кинуть хоть какую-нибудь ссылку на книжку C++11 Thread, я ни то что русскую, даже английскую не смог найти!

Comment: Да, именно эта книжка Танненбаума.
А вот ссылка на желанную книжку http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/17636939/